# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol when building for x64 platform

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit, lnk2001

The project builds on Win32 platform, but not on x64.

Full error message:
dllentry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CFactoryTemplate * g_Templates" (?g_Templates@@3PAVCFactoryTemplate@@A)

The dllentry.cpp compiles on both platforms. It contains the external declarations:

```
extern CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[];
extern int g_cTemplates;
```

g_Templates[] is then used in two functions:

```
__control_entrypoint(DllExport) STDAPI DllGetClassObject(__in REFCLSID rClsID,
    __in REFIID riid, __deref_out void **pv)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < g_cTemplates; i++)
    {
        const CFactoryTemplate * pT = &g_Templates[i];
    }
}
```

and

```
DllInitClasses(BOOL bLoading)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < g_cTemplates; i++)
    {
        const CFactoryTemplate * pT = &g_Templates[i];
    }
}
```

I checked all the libraries in the project settings and all seems to be OK, the 64 bit versions are used. What should I do to make the project build for x64 platform?

Comment: Where is the definition (not declaration) of g_Templates? Is it possible that file was omitted from the x64 configuration?

Comment: To locate the problem try to remove `extern` from the line `extern CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated in a comment to an earlier answer

> The other, valid definition, is in myClass.cpp (main class of my
>   project) 'CFactoryTemplate* g_Templates=0;' followed by 'int
>   g_cTemplates=0;' at the uppermost level in the file, just after the
>   includes.

Your definition of of `g_Templates` is inconsistent with its declaration.

The declaration is

```
extern CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[];
```

This declares `g_Templates` as an array of `CFactoryTemplate` (of unknown size). But your definition of

```
CFactoryTemplates* g_Templates = 0;
```

defines it as a pointer to a `CFactoryTemplate`, which is not the same thing.

Therefore, you failed to provide a definition of `g_Templates` that matches the declaration, and the error message is correct.

You need to get the declaration and definition to agree. One way is to write

```
CFactoryTemplates g_Templates[1];
```

to create a definition that is consistent with the declaration. (Note that zero-length arrays are disallowed in C++, so instead we create an array of length 1 and ignore the element in it.)

Another is to change the declaration to

```
extern CFactoryTemplates* g_Templates;
```

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in extern declarations. I tested with VC2012 and it didn't have a problem matching `extern int g[]` with `int* g` in another module.

Comment: But perhaps VC is wrong since further testing shows that while the linker accepts this, the two `g`s end up being different things (and the debug inspector is very confused).

Comment: @dff Arrays do not decay to pointers in extern declarations. They decay to pointers during lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and when declared as function parameters, but a declaration is neither.

Comment: Ok; but in that case what's the explanation for the fact that the error message in dllentry.cpp (where `g_Templates` is declared as an array) is "unresolved external symbol "class CFactoryTemplate * g_Templates""?

Comment: @dff There must be a pointer-style declaration visible to dllentry.cpp somewhere.

Comment: I have substantially lost confidence in VC on this subject, but there too when I put `extern int g[];` at the top of some cpp and then try to build the error message states that the undefined external symbol is `int* g`

Comment: @RaymondChen This error is from Microsoft's DirectShow base classes code (i.e. what you compile to get `strmbase.lib` so you can write DirectShow filters in C++).

The weird part is that if you don't have `g_Templates` and `g_cTemplates` defined anywhere, the code will happily link under x86, but complain about missing externals under x64.

Also, Windows SDK 10.0.20348.0 seems to have an error in `strsafe.h` line 83 which causes link failure for `StringCchPrintf` used in `wxutil.cpp` (missing external symbol `_vsnwprintf_s` in `StringVPrintfWorkerW`).

Answer (score 0):

The statement `extern CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[];` does not actually define an array<sup>*</sup> named `g_Templates`; it simply states that one exists somewhere in the project. You are essentially telling the compiler "don't worry that you don't see this thing anywhere; when it comes time to link, you'll be able to find it in a different module." Except that apparently isn't true. Two possible reasons I can think of are (1) The file that contains the actual definition of `g_Templates` is not being included in the x64 build configuration, and (2) the definition, wherever it is, is surrounded with something like `#ifdef x86`.

To solve this, you'll need to locate the actual definition of `g_Templates` (maybe search for "CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[") and then determine why it is being omitted in the x64 build.

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically it is treated as a pointer here

Comment: g_templates is defined in sysclock.cpp, another DirectShow base class, but only under #ifdef FILTER_DLL, condition which is not satisfied in Win32 neither. The other, valid definition, is in myClass.cpp (main class of my project) 'CFactoryTemplate* g_Templates=0;' followed by 'int g_cTemplates=0;' at the uppermost level in the file, just after the includes. myClass.cpp also compiles by itself. Only the build doesn't work.

Comment: From the original code I gather that you're making a dll and the link error is occurring there. Is myClass.cpp included in that dll, or is it in a separate exe project?